# Some Asian characters not visible in mx text component

Tags: apache-flex

I have an mx text component in which Asian characters don't display, but only sometimes. The behavior is not consistent. I am using system fonts. Any non Asian characters still show up. This is happening across multiple browsers and operating systems.

Comment: When you say "Any non Asian", have you actually tested the rest of Unicode?